# Function is executed 1 in 10 chances, function doesn't make required changes

Tags: javascript

Using the following Javascript code I'm occurring 1 issue.

TL;DR:
My if statement within isOverflown function is executed only 1 out of 10 website loads. In the 9 attempts it doesn't even reach the inside of if. Although nothing changes, just reloaded website.

How to decrease font size gradually? Such as FONTSIZE -= 0.1;

---

```js
function isOverflown() {
  alert("test");
  var element=document.querySelectorAll('.eventBoxTitle');
  for(var i=0;
  i < element.length;
  i++) if (element[i].offsetWidth < element[i].scrollWidth) {
    element[i].style.fontSize="small";
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () { //if finished loading 
    isOverflown(); 
    });
```

```html
<div id="title" class="eventBoxTitle">
  <h2>Become a star!</h2>
</div>
```

1. The function is executed in fact, every time website launches. Although the "if" statement, is only executed once within 10 attempts, even though the website layout/specification stays completely same.

Secondly my question is how to gradually/dynamically change fontSize? I don't have fontsize specified as it's pure H2 header. Although my plan is to make font adjustments until it fits the box, such as fontSize -= 0.1; So it gradually decreases the font size. How to accomplish such goal?

p.s. "alert(test)" is included so you can actually see that it enters that function.

Comment: it's really not clear what you are trying to ask here.

Comment: Such be clear now ;) Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I'd use the `onload` property of the `<body>` tag, it doesn't fail. Those event listeners they act up sometimes and can behave differently across different browsers. That or jQuery, vanilla JS is out of style and having to fix problems like this yourself is swimming against the tide. Just use ol'reliable jQuery.

Comment: Before I move onto jQuery, I need to know how to use Javascript itself. It's not great to use a great tool without knowing its fundamentals.

Comment: You will just catch a bunch of bad habits on the way, trust me. There will be plenty of room to use JS even having jQuery in your toolbox.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've included "onload" into my body and now it works flawlessly. Plus, I'm opened about using jQuery, although sometimes doing it yourself will teach you something. jQuery isn't an answer to everything! :P Thanks for help with the 1st part of the question! :D